# Initialize new[] using copy constructor

Tags: c++

I believe this is a simple question with probably a not simple answer.

Here is the code:

```
template<typename T>
T* copy(T* original, int size) {
    T* result = new T[size];
    // At this point the default constructor of all new T objects have been called.

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        // This will call the assignment operator= on all new T objects
        result[i] = original[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to initialize the newly allocated memory using the **copy constructor** of T instead of using **default constructor followed by assignment operator**?

The purpose is to copy each element to its analogous element in the new array using the copy constructor of T.

I imagine there could be a way to do that by allocating memory using `malloc`, then calling the copy constructor for each element but I don't know how.

Here is an example solution from my imagination. If this is correct or this is the best we can get, tell me. Or propose a better solution:

```
template<typename T>
T* copy(T* original, int size) {
    T* result = malloc(sizeof(T)*size);
    // At this point the default constructor of all new T objects have been called.

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        T t(original[i]);
        memcpy(result+i*sizeof(T), &t, sizeof(T));
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Note:** Raw pointers are being used for simplicity.

**Note 2:** I don't need a vector. This pattern will be used to copy the underlying data structure of more complicated objects.

Comment: Answer is "Yes". I'd rather worry about the undefined behaviour though.

Comment: @Meena Alfons Arrays have neither copy constructor nor the copy assignment operator.

Comment: No, there is no syntax for this and you cannot emulate this because array allocation usually has an additional header with a number of elements that need to be destroyed by `delete[]`. But do you have to use `new[]`/`delete[]` or can you allocate memory using global `operator new`?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I need to copy each element to the analogous new element.

Comment: @StaceyGirl I don't have to use `new`, if there is a way to do it with malloc or other function to allocate memory then to call the copy constructor of each element, that would be great.

Comment: @MeenaAlfons That is you need a copy constructor for a created dynamically array but arrays do not have copy constructors.:)

Comment: See an example solution I just added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to allocate memory by any other means, but keep in mind that `size * sizeof(T)` can overflow. `std::allocator` takes care of this.

Use [`std::uninitialized_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy)/[`std::uninitialized_copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy_n) to perform the copy:

```
template<typename T>
T* copy(T* original, int size) {
    std::allocator<T> alloc;
    T* result = alloc.allocate(size);
    try {
        std::uninitialized_copy_n(original, size, result);
    } catch (...) {
        alloc.deallocate(result, size);
        throw;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Later you can use [`std::destroy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy)/[`std::destroy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_n) to destroy them and deallocate memory:

```
template<typename T>
void destroy(T* ptr, int size)
{
    std::destroy_n(ptr, size);
    std::allocator<T>().deallocate(ptr, size);
}
```

This should work unless you need to be able to delete them with operator `delete[]` - in which case there is no solution for this.

If you are implementing a custom container, you can use template allocator like standard containers do:

```
template<typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
struct container
{
    [[no_unique_address]] Allocator allocator;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Good answer to the point, but why `delete[]` will not work. AFAIK it should call the destructor for each element then free the allocated memory. What is missing?

Comment: @MeenaAlfons If type has non-empty destructor, there is an additional header allocated before the actual array with a number of elements stored - this header is used by `delete[]` to know how many objects need to be destroyed. Essentially pointer returns by `new` is allocated block plus header size. So it is a combination of compile-time and runtime decision making. You will have to interfere with `new` ABI to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.

Comment: Nice solution. Maybe one could think about wrapping everything in a unique_ptr like this: `auto deleter =[size] (T* t) { destroy(t ,size);}; std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(deleter)> {result, deleter}; `. But of course bad things will happen, when one puts a pointer pointing to an array of different length in there.

Comment: @MeenaAlfons I have added the try-catch block. I think omitting it was a mistake, but it does make example bigger and it was missing in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

For the `new` operator I don't think so.

But **yes** there is. It's called `std::vector`:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> copy(T* original, int size) {
   return std::vector<T>{original, original + size};
}
```

Because you don't follow RAII and use owning raw pointers your code is not memory leak free, so don't do that! Use C++ properly.

Comment: See **Note** and **Note2**